# c# select one generic list into new form

Tags: c#, list, linq, group-by

I've the following class and generic list:

```
      public class maxFormat
        {
            public string asin { get; set; }              
            public string _new { get; set; }
            public string _likenew { get; set; }
            public string _verygood { get; set; }
            public string _good { get; set; }
            public string _acceptable { get; set; }
        }    

          List[MaxFormat] lstMax= new List[MaxFormat]();
```

I need to make some price calculation on around 2 million records and then add the results into the my generic list then i need to flatten the results into one. The field called "asin" is common for my records and one asin can have multiple prices like "new","good" etc.

So i've tried the FirstOrDefault() property of the linq to find and update if an asin already have a price but it doesnt give result. i think it takes too long.

Finally i decided to add records first and then group by and distinct them using linq to flatten results into one but performance is not enough for me because of **Select** property projects each element of a sequence. So these operations are performed for all elements.

```
 var Final = maxFormat.GroupBy(x => x.asin ).Select(y => new
            {
                asin = y.Key.asin,
                _new = y.Where(z => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(z._new)).Select(z => z._new).FirstOrDefault(),
                _likenew = y.Where(z => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(z._likenew)).Select(z => z._likenew).FirstOrDefault(),
                _verygood = y.Where(z => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(z._verygood)).Select(z => z._verygood).FirstOrDefault(),
                _good = y.Where(z => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(z._good)).Select(z => z._good).FirstOrDefault(),
                _acceptable = y.Where(z => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(z._acceptable)).Select(z => z._acceptable).FirstOrDefault()

            }).Distinct().ToList();
```

So these codes are working fine but i need to improve the performance.

**I need something like in EX:**

Existing records in list:

1. > ASIN=0000000001 New Price= **50.1**; LikeNew Price = NULL; VeryGood Price= NULL;
   >   Good Price=NULL;Acceptable Price= NULL;
2. > ASIN=0000000001 New Price= NULL; LikeNew Price = **25**; VeryGood Price= NULL;
   >   Good Price=NULL;Acceptable Price= NULL;

Final result in **var Final**:

> ASIN=0000000001 New Price= **50.1**; LikeNew Price = **25**; VeryGood Price= NULL;
>   Good Price=NULL;Acceptable Price= NULL;

Any suggestions?

Comment: To improve performance create a dictionary so you can look up items quicker.

Comment: Seems to me like it's a poor data design in the first place... where does this data come from?

Comment: Instead of `y.Where(z => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(z._new)).Select(z => z._new).FirstOrDefault()` nicer to do: `y.FirstOrDefault(z => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(z._new))?._new`

Comment: Sounds like a job for the database to handle and not in code.

Comment: Well thanks for answers. I'm using SQL server 2014 and my SELECT statement is something like "SELECT t1.[asin],t1.[new],t1.[likenew],t1.[verygood],t1.[good],t1.[acceptable]FROM [dbo].[asin_yf] AS t1"

Comment: After fetching my old price data from Database then i use FOREACH statement in my c# code to calculate new prices of each asin. After that i need to flatten that new calculated list into one so i can print or do some stuff with that flatten result. Well thats what i ask for a help.

Comment: @GiladGreen i'll try it asap thanks

Comment: I second the comments here; I could give you a basic answer, but if you have to treat millions of records, Linq is clearly not the tool you want; heck, even C# isn't the tool you want, that's a database job.

Comment: So you have one table in database with multiple rows regarding one "primary key"? Why not just fix your data?

Comment: @JanneMatikainen yes and could you be more specific? I can fetch around 2 million data from database to generic list in c# without issue. My problem is flattenning that results after some huge calculations which takes parameters on method that something that i cant handle it from database..

Comment: @harun, construct a view where you will flatten the data for your calculations instead of attempting to do that in code with linq. Can't really say how your data is constructed/verified to be coherent with your current data scheme, but you can write a materialized view which will do the same as you are trying to do in linq with either few joins or sub queries depending on the state of your data. Which I assume is not very coherent as no primary key is present, so you can have multiple "New Price" rows for same ASIN code.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen thanks for advice i'll give it a try (View thing).
The asin field is unique
Btw my database scheme is like below:

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[asin_yf](
 [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [asin] [varchar](10) NOT NULL, 
 [new] [float] NOT NULL,
 [likenew] [float] NOT NULL,
 [verygood] [float] NOT NULL,
 [good] [float] NOT NULL,
 [acceptable] [float] NOT NULL, 
 CONSTRAINT [PK_asin1_yf] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: The asin field is unique therefore there can be only one of the same conditon/price.

Comment: I have no idea how you end up with your existing records in the list with the claimed database structure and constraints.

Comment: In your code `var Final = maxFormat`... what is `maxFormat`?